# IOS 7 QR Code Creation after paypal purchase

Tags: ios, ios7, paypal, qr-code

Hi I am developing an app that will sell tickets to events using the paypal ios sdk. I am new to the sdk and I am trying to generate a qr code as a digital ticket for a buyer after a ticket is purchased through paypal. I have been able to setup the sdk and purchase items through the paypal sandbox, but I am now stuck. Below are the questions I have come up with:

- Once a buyer purchases a ticket, what can the app use from the paypal ios sdk to know when a ticket has been purchased?
- Are there any libraries out there that can manage QR Code creation after a ticket is purchased?

I have seen this done in several apps, I just have not been able to find any information on it.

Thanks.

Comment: See this implementation of QR code encoder for Objective-C  https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C

Comment: As you are targeting iOS you should also investigate passbook - it does have a server-side requirement but offers a standard way for users to access passes, such as tickets